# LaravelCollective v6.2: Undefined class 'Form' in PhpStorm

Tags: forms, phpstorm, laravelcollective

I have just installed LaravelCollective v6.2 running `$ composer require laravelcollective/html` command.

I made a form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/posts']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputTitle"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Enter title"
                   name="title">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

PhpStorm says Undefined class 'Form'. How can I fix this?

[image]

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2"
    },
```

Comment: Do you use [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)? If you do -- you need to regenerate the IDE helper file so it includes `Form` facade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` is a Laravel facade. Quite a bit of magic is involved here.

Do you use [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) by Barry vd. Heuvel?

- If you do not: install and use it. It generates special `.php` file(s) that are used by the IDE to better understand the Laravel related code (facades and other Laravel stuff).
- If you do: you need to re-generate the IDE helper file so it includes the `Form` facade.